# How to show ampersand mnemonic in design-time for a UserControl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

**On design-time:**

Scenario 1: When placing ampersands in a regular control, the underline for the succeeding character **is shown**.

Scenario 2: When doing this for a `UserControl`, it doesn't (While yes the mnemonic works on runtime).

Just being OC here, but is there a way to make it work like in scenario 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by what m.k mentioned. At first, the mnemonic in the `UserControl` does not show on design-time, but once you press Alt key, it shows now.

Answer (score 1):

try to do it in the code, for example:

```
control.Text="...&..."
```

if you do it by the property window, you cause to activate the control by alt+the letter after &.